# How to cut one group of faces with another group of faces?

Tags: mesh

First off, I would like to apologize for any mis-terming or anything of the like, as this is my first blender project. I'm trying to make a mesh model, and I like to have everything neat and connected. I have run into one problem multiple times, that is that I need to connect two parts of the mesh at a certain point, which is inside another face. Is there any way that I can use both face to "cut" each other, sort of making a cross a corner? I have some screenshots below for clarification.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand. Do you aim to use one group of faces as a "knife" to cut another group of faces? or do you need to simply split some faces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and use edit mode *Boolean Operations* (only available in Blender 2.77+)

Go into edit mode, select one of the groups of faces you want to use, open the Spacebar Menu and search for *Boolean*. Then choose one the the options that suits you best.

If you need the original intact faces you may need to create a copy of your objects first.

[image: Edit mode booleans]

Have in mind that these will merge faces together and likely result in bad topology and non manifold meshes.

You should always strive for clean topology manifold meshes, and quad-based or quad-dominant topology

Comment: That worked well enough for a noob's first model! Thank you!

Comment: I downvoted because "Use boolean operations" is not descriptive, nor does it even attempt to clarify how one might get to said options. And on top of this, spacebar is not bound to the search function by default: https://stackoverflowsolutions.com/topic/product-guides/how-to-ask-and-answer