# Make edge at intersection

Tags: modeling, faces

So i'm creating a boat, but now i want the floor cut off because of the inclination of the hull. The picture will make it more clear. [image]
[image]

How should i go about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Could you add more pictures from different angles and maybe draw some in them to explain?

Comment: Sounds like knife project could do what you want, but it would have to be separated into a different object. Could you please elaborate, is not very clear what you are trying to achieve from that image alone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cut one group of faces with another group of faces?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58687/how-to-cut-one-group-of-faces-with-another-group-of-faces)

Comment: The horizontal surface you see is the floor. The other two faces are part off the hull of the boat. What i now want, it that the floor, the horizontal face, get's cut off whenever it get's outside of the hull. The red section in the image below, has to be cut off.
Edit: Because i can't add an image, i added the image in the OP

Comment: My naive approach would be to snap the vertices to the face, delete the face(s), then recreate the face(s) such that they include the new vertices. There's probably a better way.

Comment: Thanks, but i there a way i can snap to the intersection of the face and the vertex, because when i try to snap it to the face, whenever i drag my mouse along the face, it snaps to that y, instead of the y with the same x and z.